# Error: Error reading rules file firestore.rules

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to deploy my website while using Firebase as a host and deleted the `firestore.rules` file as I didn't think that I required the use of the Cloud Firestore database (I'm just deploying a placeholder for now).

I have followed all the steps as mentioned in [their documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/deploying).

When I run `firebase deploy` I get the error:

`Error: Error reading rules file firestore.rules`

I don't know how to move past this. Can someone please help me with a solution to this? Thank you!

Comment: At least in the spanish version of that documentation link, there is no advice on deleting that file, and your error message suggest it was needed. Did you make a backup of it you could restore?

Comment: No, I didn't back it up. Is there any way that I can re-download it? (Perhaps uninstall and reinstall the Firebase CLI, or things of that sort?)

Comment: Not sure, havent used firestore, but maybe [this doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started) can help you.

Comment: @Vaibhav, did you get happy?

Answer (score 1):

## How to retrieve your existing Cloud Firestore rules

Go to your `Firebase Console` and click on `Cloud Firestore` from the `Build` category in the sidebar.
You can see a `Rules` tab on the top of the screen (below the Cloud Firestore heading). Open the `Rules` tab. Now you can see the rules which are currently active and all the other ones you have deployed so far (via CLI or Firebase Console).

You can copy your rules from here and paste it in a file called `firestore.rules` in your project folder.

[image: Cloud Firestore Rules Tab]

## How to fix the error "Error: Error reading rules file firestore.rules"

This error will most likely appear if you have set a wrong path for the `firestore.rules` in your `firebase.json` file (e.g. moved the file to a subfolder) or you don't have a `firestore.rules` file at all but reference it in the `firebase.json`.

### Wrong path set in firebase.json

Open your `firebase.json` file from your Firebase project folder. You can find some paths and filenames in this file.

Look for the `firestore` category. It should look similar to this:

```
"firestore": {
  "rules": "firestore.rules",
  "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
},
```

You may want to update your paths or filenames to match where your `firestore.rules` are located.

If you can't find any paths for `firestore` you can add them to your `firebase.json` file. It may now look like this (note: I've moved my firestore files and changed the path of the `firestore.rules` and `firestore.indexes.json`):

```
{
  "firestore": {
    "rules": "firestore/firestore.rules",
    "indexes": "firestore/firestore.indexes.json"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
  },
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint",
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run build"
    ],
    "source": "functions"
  }
}
```

### If you don't want to deploy any Firestore rules from your project folder

If you want to deploy your `Firestore rules` just over the `Firebase Console` you can delete the `firestore.rules` and `firestore.indexes.json` files from your project folder and delete the `firestore` part from your `firebase.json`. Although I recommend to keep them in your project folder so you can keep track of them in your version control system.

Keep in mind that you may also just delete the reference in the `firebase.json` file that the `rules` aren't deployed via the CLI and keep the `firestore.rules` and `firestore.indexes.json` files.

**Delete this if you don't want to deploy your Firestore rules via the CLI:**

```
"firestore": {
  "rules": "firestore.rules",
  "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
},
```

Comment: The path to firestore.rules fixed it in my case. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

if you're following this tutorial
https://firebase.google.com/codelabs/firebase-web#14 then the issue here is when you try to deploy running this command `firebase deploy --except functions` then this script will try to look for files with `firestore.rules` and `storage.rules` in the root directory and you'll get the following `Error: Error reading rules file storage.rules` this file because you told to do so in.

So to deploy it successfully with `firebase deploy --except functions` then you have to create this files in root directory and then will work.

firebase.json file

```
{
  "firestore": {
    "rules": "firestore.rules",
    "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
  },
  "storage": {
    "rules": "storage.rules"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "./public",
    "headers": [
      {
        "source": "**/*.@(js|html)",
        "headers": [
          {
            "key": "Cache-Control",
            "value": "max-age=0"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

firestore.rules

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /messages/{messageId} {
      allow read;
      allow create, update: if request.auth != null
                    && request.resource.data.name == request.auth.token.name
                    && (request.resource.data.text is string
                      && request.resource.data.text.size() <= 300
                      || request.resource.data.imageUrl is string
                      && request.resource.data.imageUrl.matches('https?://.*'));
      allow delete: if false;
    }
    match /fcmTokens/{token} {
      allow read: if false;
      allow write;
    }
  }
}
```

storage.rules

```
// Returns true if the uploaded file is an image and its size is below the given number of MB.
function isImageBelowMaxSize(maxSizeMB) {
  return request.resource.size < maxSizeMB * 1024 * 1024
      && request.resource.contentType.matches('image/.*');
}

service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{userId}/{messageId}/{fileName} {
      allow write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId && isImageBelowMaxSize(5);
      allow read;
    }
  }
}
```

So with this 2 file `firestore.rules` and `storage.rules` added to root directory the deploy command should work.

Answer (score 0):

Add the `firestore.rules` attribute pointing to `firestore.rules`
this what the dics at firebase website says:

then change:

```
{
    // Add this!
    "firestore": {
        "rules": "firestore.rules"
},
```

to:

```
{
    // Add this!
    "firestore": {
        "firestore.rules": "firestore.rules"
},
```

this worked for me

Answer (score 0):

**Follow these steps:**

1. Go to firebase.json.
2. Add this code :

   {
   "hosting": {
   "public": "./public",
   "headers": [{
   "source" : "**/*.@(js|html)",
   "headers" : [ {
   "key" : "Cache-Control",
   "value" : "max-age=0"
   } ]
   }]
   }
   }
3. Run firebase deploy --except functions.

** PS **: I assume you already changed the rules in the Firebase dashboard.

Answer (score -1):

delete :"rules": "firestore.rules",   from firebase.json file

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Your answer would be improved by some more explanation. Please see [answer].